# How to store result of 1 column/multiple rows result set into multiple variables, 1 per row

Tags: variables, automation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I store result of a [1 column but multiple rows] result set into multiple variables, every row stored into a new variable.

Ex. :
If I have the following query:

select distinct employee from Employee_Table

Result:

| Column A |
| --- |
| John |
| Ron |
| Smith |
| Aaron |

How Can I easily store the result of the query into 4 variables (because there are 4 distinct employees in this example).
Ex. Var1 = John, Var2 = Ron, Var 3 = Smith, Var4 = Aaron
(I ask because I would like to do this on a larger scale, with 50+ variables)

Thank you,
K

Ex. Var1 = John, Var2 = Ron, Var 3 = Smith, Var4 = Aaron

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am very very curious about your use case for setting 50+ variables. What exactly are you trying to do?